# Issue removing objects out of observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, observablecollection

I have an ItemsControl which has a Canvas as ItemsPanelTemplate and an ellipse as ItemTemplate. What I want to do is when I drag an existing Ellipse I want it to be removed out of my observable collection of EllipseXY objects, meaning it will be removed from my Canvas as well. My drag event passes on an EllipseXY object which can then be compared in the Drop event. However when I remove the EllipseXY object in my collection it remains shown on my canvas despite the Remove being triggered. What could be the possible reasons?

Model:

```
public class EllipseXY
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public Ellipse EllipseObject { get; set; }
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
private ObservableCollection<EllipseXY> ellipses;
    public ObservableCollection<EllipseXY> Ellipses
    {
        get { return ellipses; }
        set
        {
            if (ellipses == null)
            {
                ellipses = new ObservableCollection<EllipseXY>();
                ellipses = value;
            }
            else
            {
                ellipses = value;

            }
RaisePropertyChanged("Ellipses");
        }
    }

 #region EllipseXY
    public EllipseXY EllipseXY
    {
        get { return ellipsexy; }
        set
        {
            ellipsexy = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("EllipseXY");
        }
    }

    public Ellipse EllipseObject
    {
        get { return ellipsexy.EllipseObject; }
        set
        {
            ellipsexy.EllipseObject = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("EllipseObject");
        }
    }

    public double X
    {
        get { return ellipsexy.X; }
        set
        {
            ellipsexy.X = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("X");
        }
    }

    public double Y
    {
        get { return ellipsexy.Y; }
        set
        {
            ellipsexy.Y = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Y");
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Drag:

```
DataObject dragObject= new DataObject("dragObject", elliXY);
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dragEllipse, dragObject, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

Drop (not all the code but the only relevant one to this question):

```
Model.EllipseXY ellipseXY = (Model.EllipseXY)e.Data.GetData("dragObject");
Ellipses.Remove(ellipseXY);
```

I also tried using LINQ:

```
        EllipseXY test = (EllipseXY)Ellipses.Where(ellipse => ellipse.EllipseObject.Fill == dropEllipse.Fill);
        Ellipses.Remove(test);
```

But with no success :P

Edit XAML:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Ellipses}" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Name="CanvasDrop" Margin="10,0,10,0" Width="500" Height="400"
                            ClipToBounds="True" Background="{Binding Image}" AllowDrop="True" IsItemsHost="True">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                                <gala:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DragCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">
                                <gala:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DropCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="Ellipse">
                    <Ellipse Fill="{Binding EllipseObject.Fill}" Style="{StaticResource ellipseStyle}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Can you show how your `ItemsControl` binds to the `Ellipses` list?

Comment: Try public class EllipseXY : INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Farzi: How is that supposed to help? The question is not about changing any attributes of an `EllipseXY` instance, but about modifying the list.

Comment: Although it's unlikely to be the cause, you've picked strange way to set value of the `Ellipses` property. Shouldn't the `if` statement be moved to the `get` method?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the complete question !!

Comment: @Grx70: If we assume a lazy initialization, possibly, though I *suspect* the condition *should* read `value == null`. In that case, it would totally make sense to have the `if` statement in the setter (as a way to ensure that the private `ellipses` field can never be `null`), except that `RaisePropertyChanged` should probably be moved to be outside of the `if` statement.

Comment: Concerning your use of LINQ methods - what exactly happened when you had "no success"? An exception? Because [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable`, which cannot be casted into an `EllipseXY` ... try using [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535050%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of `Where` and see what happens.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That seemed to have done the trick! However if I would want to remove one based on all 3 values (ellipse, x, y) is this possible with LINQ?

Comment: @NielsW: I outlined how to do that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item you pass to [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) needs to be the same *instance*, not just an object that has the same values.

I suspect that is not currently the case, as your filter based on item properties did the trick, as described in your comment:

```
EllipseXY test = (EllipseXY)Ellipses.First(ellipse => ellipse.EllipseObject.Fill == dropEllipse.Fill);
Ellipses.Remove(test);
```

Like this, `test` references an actual instance that is in the list, which conforms to the filter expression.

You can further narrow down your selection, either by creating a more complex boolean expression (`(ellipse.EllipseObject.Fill == dropEllipse.Fill) && (ellipse ...`), or by inserting several calls to [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) before the call to `First`, one for each criterion.

Answer (score 0):

This is just odd
If ellipses is null you ignore the value and don't call RaisePropertyChanged.

```
public ObservableCollection<EllipseXY> Ellipses
{
    get { return ellipses; }
    set
    {
        if (ellipses == null) ellipses = new ObservableCollection<EllipseXY>();
        else
        {
            ellipses = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Ellipses");
        }
    }
}
```

Here you have a different Notify from the property

```
public EllipseXY EllipseXY
{
    get { return ellipsexy; }
    set
    {
        ellipsexy = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Ellipse");
    }
}
```

What is llipses?

Your code is not getting better

```
private ObservableCollection<EllipseXY> ellipses;
public ObservableCollection<EllipseXY> Ellipses
{
    get { return ellipses; }
    set
    {
        if (ellipses == null)
        {
            ellipses = new ObservableCollection<EllipseXY>();
            ellipses = value;
        }
        else
        {
            ellipses = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Ellipses");
        }
    }
}
```

why would you set ellipses = new ObservableCollection(); then immediately set ellipses = value;
Why RaisePropertyChanged("Ellipses"); in the else?

Try this

```
private ObservableCollection<EllipseXY> ellipses = new ObservableCollection<EllipseXY>();
public ObservableCollection<EllipseXY> Ellipses
{
    get { return ellipses; }
    set
    {
        if (ellipses == value) return; 
        ellipses = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Ellipses");
    }
}
```

To add to the answer from Mapper
This is the line that is probably breaking it

```
DataObject dragObject= new DataObject("dragObject", elliXY);
```

You are creating a new Object
Another solution is to override GetHashCode and Equals in EllipseXY

Comment: While totally correct in all aspects, this does not answer the question; I think it is more suitable as a comment.

Comment: It didn't copy paste everything it's supposed to say Ellipses :). Thanks for pointing out about ignoring the value as well as the raisepropertychanged typo.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The lack of a call to RaisePropertyChanged("Ellipses"); may be the problem.

Comment: @Blam: Hardly so. The relevant code shown by the OP (`Ellipses.Remove(test);`) does not change the list object, it changes the items *within the list*. The [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should take care of notifying any subscribers about that change. The `RaisePropertyChanged("Ellipses")` only becomes relevant if the *list instance* itself is exchanged.

Comment: Updated the question. Should have all updated code now. The Remove gets called but doesn't actually remove anything out of the list btw.

Comment: @NielsW: Please clarify: Does it actually remove anything out of the *list* (i.e. the list still contains the item in question when you check its value with debugging tools at a breakpoint), as you are implying now in this comment, or does the item just not disappear from the *Canvas*, as you implied in your question? Have you checked the return value of `Remove`?

Comment: The item remains in the list so it is still shown in the Canvas as well. Before the remove the count is 1 & after the remove the count is still 1 (only added one Ellipse for testing purposes). So the problem is that it isn't removed out of the list, once it's removed out of the list it will automatically be removed from the canvas as well.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Exactly. If the list get swapped out without calling Notify there is a problem.

Comment: @Blam: Yes, but that does not happen in `Ellipses.Remove(ellipseXY);`

Comment: The .Remove does indeed not call the RaisePropertyChanged but how do I make it so that it does? @Blam I had already updated my RaisePropertyChanged location before you edited your post but your code is much cleaner thank you.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper  Flopping out a list without a Notify is not good for the UI and can have lingering effects.  Can we just let the OP see if it fixes it?

Comment: @Blam: Where do you see the list getting flipped in the statement `Ellipses.Remove(ellipseXY);`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Let it go.  I said flopping out a list without a Notify is not good for the UI.  I did not say it happened in that statement.

Comment: @Blam: Hence my initial statement that "this does not answer the question; I think it is more suitable as a comment."